# Rails on Windows is so slow (rails -v takes 4 seconds)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, windows-vista

I'm using rails Version 3.0.3 and ruby Version 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-15) on a Intel Core 2 Duo 2,6 Ghz with 4 GB Ram and Windows Vista Business SP2 with no other (heavy) applications running. I have already read that rails development on Windows is slower than on Unices and most people do there for not recommend it but this is silly.

I can't think of any good reason for using 4 seconds to display a simple Version number. And rails generate needs up to 10 seconds to complete!

Something in my setup must be wrong (at least I hope).

Has someone a good idea how to proceed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Windows is optimized heavily for backwards compatibility and feature lists. Not for the performance of dynamically-typed, interpreted, runtime-loaded scripting languages. Use Linux. You can run Linux in a window within Windows if you use VirtualBox.

Comment: After a few months fighting with Rails on Windows, I'm using Ubuntu in VirtualBox. Been great so far. But I totally agree that it is ridiculous that Windows users are often out in the cold when it comes to Rails and to a lesser extent Ruby.

Comment: And, I host all Rails stuff in the Ubuntu VM, but all code is stored in the Windows host and all editing is on Windows.

Comment: @Justice, Windows has nothing to do with optimizing for "dynamically-typed, interpreted, runtime-loaded scripting languages". Ruby is just another executable program. Point me to some resources if you think I'm wrong.

Comment: and I think people should stfu when answering similar questions with "Switch to linux". How is that helping anyone?

Comment: 28sec for me to run "time rails generate"

Comment: For me, "time rails g" takes 28sec. But with same machine, same window 7 and within VM(vagrant-Ubuntu) "time rails g" takes 1sec(0.9sec)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few key points that combined generate the slow performance you're noticing.

- Ruby IO performance (on any version) is up to 3 times slower than Linux counterparts. This is because several unoptimized hops in the Windows codebase of Ruby. This requires further analysis, investigation and optimization not done until today.
- Ruby 1.9.2 produces several `stat()` calls per file been required, which can increase the slowdown of Ruby itself. This is not present in Ruby 1.8.6 or 1.8.7. This is also solved in Ruby 1.9.3 (trunk) not released yet.
- Projects like Rails requires around 500 files, which combined with above points make Ruby for Windows the snail lot of folks see.

Now, there are workaround to that, some simple and some complex ones.

1. Move back to Ruby 1.8.7 instead of Ruby 1.9.2. That will bring again certain level of speed to your application. Unless you're taking advantage of Unicode support, then 1.8.7 could work for you.
2. Look into tools like Spork to provide scenario/forking for your RSpec/Cucumber
3. Move your development to RAM, using a RAMDisk like [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk). Move both Ruby and your application to it and time of loading will be reduced (this is associated with your available RAM too)

Hope some of these options help you.

Comment: Using 1.8.7 reduced the time for "rails -v" below one second. It's really faster. Thx.

Comment: Just to save new people some time:  ImDisk may not have any effect on your numbers on Ruby 1.9.3.  We have a set of tests that take 100 seconds on Linux, they still take over 2 thousand seconds on Windows, ram disk or no ram disk.

Comment: @Jason the improvements mentioned were about startup time, not running time. If your tests are too I/O bound (network, database, etc) then they will still take a long time to complete). Luckily Ruby 2.0 got the performance patch in so startup will be faster.

Comment: It's not the tests, it's the quantity (over 800).  One theory is that it has to do with loading all the code/gems to run the tests.  ImDisk didn't help at all, but Xavier's patch ( http://rhnh.net/2011/05/28/speeding-up-rails-startup-time ) gets me about a 4x improvement.  Hard disk versus ImDisk makes less than 1% difference.

Comment: Something I recommend you look at: https://gist.github.com/3242245 this was merged into Ruby 2.0, so that will mitigate most of the performance issues shown on Windows. You can download automated builds of Ruby 2.0 as indicated here: https://gist.github.com/3251384

Comment: That is pretty nifty, but sadly only as fast as Xavier's patch.  Still stuck at 445 seconds.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons why your tests don't go faster. What I outlined in my response to the poster is one scenario: startup time and how that is affecting ruby. I have no idea what else your tests do (honestly don't care) as it would be great you post about those on a place ruby core developers can help and not here, which can be considered a passive aggressive attitude (complaining about something to someone that has no power to help you)

Comment: Err, yes, sorry.  I should have left it at "ImDisk won't necessarily help you"

Comment: I have the same issue with rails -v running about 5 secs, but on Mac Os (rails 5.0.0, ruby 2.3.3). For example Laravel artisan command runs in milliseconds.

Answer (score 7):

It is faster to use Ruby inside an Ubuntu Virtual Machine than using it directly with Windows.

A good option is to use Vagrant: You develop on your Windows IDE, and files are "shared" with the Ubuntu VM, you run "vagrant ssh", then run "rails server", or any other command you'd like to run. There are other benefits as well:

- Your don't need to install RVM, or switch ruby versions, just use a VM for each project. VMs can be small, like 500MB of data, using up to 100MB of RAM, but YMMV
- You don't need to worry about gem's compatibility with Windows

Take a look: http://www.vagrantup.com/

Answer (score -1):

For a speedup you could try my loader speeder upper (helps rails run faster in Windows): https://github.com/rdp/faster_require

Also checkout spork, which works in Windows, and jruby also works well.

Comment: I used that and it made `rake -T` take from 4.3m to 13.2m! It makes everything slower. Used global install.

Comment: Way back in the day it was the opposite.  For windows at least, gl!

Answer (score -1):

you can try playing with ruby's garbage collecter to make ruby faster, since the defaults variable settings don't match how windows work

also [Garbage collector performance tuning](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/documentation.html#_garbage_collector_performance_tuning)

Answer (score -2):

More than likely, it's anti-virus affecting it.  That combined with Vista's speed issues are probably affecting it.  I agree with Justice, run Linux in a VM.

Comment: Thanks. Would it bring some relief if I would migrate to Windows 7? I just wanted to play around a bit and it therefore is a bit overkill to install a full ubuntu. I would consider this if my programming is getting serious some how. :-)

Comment: Maybe, as Windows 7 is definitely quite a bit faster.

Comment: This is true! While it doesnt solve the problem entirely, disabling the antivirus certainly speeded up rails a bit. Especially generate commands which were slow as hell and now are acceptable.

Comment: This answer horrifies me. Turning off an anti-virus is not a _solution_. Ever. Also, even in 2011, Vista didn't really have speed issues any more, thanks to the myriad of Service Packs.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide timings with and without anti-virus instead of speculating. Then it would be a real answer instead of a comment.