# Cucumber (even without rails) Very Slow

Tags: ruby, cucumber

The simple command `cucumber -h` takes 4-6 seconds to execute on my machine.  Not surprisingly, running the most basic cucumber tests, even outside of rails, takes the same amount of time.

Is there any way to speed this up?  What exactly is taking so long, if the tests themselves are listed as running in ~100ms?

I am on win7, ruby 1.9.2, 2.5GHz processor and 6G ram.

Comment: I've used cucumber on  Windows, Unix and Linux. Only on windows are there startup delays. `cucumber -h` ran in 0.32 seconds on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: The Rails startup time on windows is particularly slow. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627888/rails-on-windows-is-so-slow-rails-v-takes-4-seconds

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong with your environment. how long does it take to run `ruby -h` or `rake -h`?

Comment: @JoshuaCheek: `ruby -h` runs instantly.

Comment: @MarkThomas: See OP -- I am running these tests outside of rails so that shouldn't be an issue.  Why would that affect the speed of `cucumber h`.  Fwiw I also tried running my tests with spork, putting `require 'Mechanize'` and `require 'json'` in the prefork block, and that actually does speed things up from about 6-7s down to 2-3s.  I wonder if that 2-3 seconds is just cucumber loading itself up -- I wonder if you could somehow rig spork to do that?

Comment: And `rake -h`? (basically the question is: is this specific to cucumber, or do all your gems have this issue?)

Comment: @JoshuaCheek: `rake -h` executes in ~1s, vs the 2-3 for cucumber.  It is definitely not instant, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issues with Cucumber being extremely slow. One major improvement you can make to the startup time is to upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 with this [patch](https://gist.github.com/1688857?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email). On my machines I've seen a 30% speedup in startup time.

Comment: Will this improve the load time of cucumber without rails as well?  Also, is the an official release?

Comment: Yes, it will help with non-rails apps as well. From what I have heard, you should still be able to get major performance improvements from the official 1.9.3 releases, which have major improvements in the performance of the 'require' statement. The patches I have linked to include additional improvements that have not been merged into the sources yet.

Comment: Upgrading to the official 1.9.3 release fixed the problem.  With that and spork, my tests now execute instantly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found (while developing a rails application) that cucumber actually slowed my testing down. I ended up using rspec with guard (and spork when I felt like it). Rspec is one of the basic rails testing suites, guard runs all of your tests intelligently (it stops after failing one test so it doesn't overwhelm you) and spork is a process that reruns your tests when you change files.

I never figured out why cucumber took so long, so I just switched back to rspec for simplicity and time.

Comment: reagan, rspec is slow for me as well.  not as slow, but even `rspec h` takes 3-4 seconds for me.  btw, are you on a windows box or mac?

Comment: I prefer the POSIX command line system when working with rails, so I'm on the pre-retina macbook pro 15" (4gb ram, slower processor than you, same ruby version)

Comment: I really enjoyed this tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:guard   it will help you setup guard and spork if you wanna give that a try

Comment: I've actually used both guard and spork before.  They are good, but didn't do anything to alleviate this basic speed problem.  I'd like to treat the root cause, though I suspect ruby and these gems are just inherently too slow